# present() method in alert view shows error

Tags: ios, swift

I can't use the method `present()`.
The error is:

> Value of type 'ProductByBrandCollectiionView' has no member 'present'

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You select\(NameArray[indexPath.row])", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    print("You select \(NameArray[indexPath.row])")
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: what type of ProductByBrandCollectiionView is?

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ProductByBrandCollectiionView` doesnt have `present` method.

`Value of type 'ProductByBrandCollectiionView' has no member 'present'`

You need to use an instance of UIViewController to show the `alert`

Comment: ProductByBrandCollectiionView is already bind with the UIViewController

Comment: What do you mean about "bind"? What type is your `ProductByBrandCollectiionView`? If it is not a UIViewController then it cannot `present`

Comment: yes its not a UIViewController but now I guess I got that how to use

Comment: here is the code line to use that method without UIViewController.     " window!.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) "

Comment: `window!.rootViewController` is an UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for your alert in your didSelectItemAt for your collection view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt
            indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You select\(NameArray[indexPath.row])", preferredStyle: .alert)

                let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in

                }

            alert.addAction(okayAction)

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
     }
```

Just make sure that your NameArray is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ProductByBrandCollectiionView is just a view, not a viewcontroller, so you cannot present a viewcontroller.
Some solutions that you can try :

- First, create a delegate, so that you can pass the action didSelectItemAt from ProductByBrandCollectiionView to your current viewcontroller.
- Or you can create a closure, working the same way with delegate above